# Website stops responding after sending file to user

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I created a site with C# which can download files. after calling

```
//A webservice returning a stream with the document data.
Stream checkOut = FileProxy.RetrieveDocument(Ticket, ID);

HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
HttpContext.Current.Response.BufferOutput = true;
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/x-download";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "atachment; filename=" + filenamevariable);
HttpContext.Current.Response.CacheControl = "public";

byte[] buffer = new byte[255];
int butesRead = 0;
while ((bytesread = checkOut.Read(buffer, 0, 255)) > 0)
{
    if(HttpContext.Current.REsponse.IsClientConnected)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    }
}
Httpcontext.Current.Response.Close();
checkOut.Close();
```

Running this code succesfully downloads the document but i can not continue using the site (Buttons don't work anymore). Am i forgetting something after the download completion?

Comment: It might be a javascript error, please post your javascript console output.

Comment: Why are you calling Response.End? I think it's often a source of issue, as you are forcing the end of the response, instead of letting it finish properlY.

Comment: Removing Response.End() doesn't change anyhting. So i was wrong from where the error originated. I'll update the post to reflect all code.

Comment: After some more debugging i found out that without Response.End() it continue's adding information to the document. So when opened next to the expected information i also got site's body. I don't know why or how. But without Response.End it works that way.